# TwinCat Sys Manager: INIT to PREOP' failed! Error: 'check product code'

Tags: plc, twincat

We have a running TwinCat project on a PC. After the restart of the machine, the following error occurs when i try to run the project in "Run Mode" or try Online Reset.

Errors:

[image: errors]

```
Type    Server (Port)   Timestamp   Message
Error    (65535)        'Term 29 (EK1100)' (1006): state change aborted (requested 'PREOP', back to 'INIT').

Error    (65535)    'Term 29 (EK1100)' (1006): 'INIT to PREOP' failed! Error: 'check product code'. Device 'EL1014-XXXX-XXXX' found and 'EK1100-0000-0018' expected.

Warning  (65535)    'Term 33 (EL1014) (1010) - Term 34 (EL1014) (1011)' Communication interrupted

Warning  (65535)    'Term 35 (EK1100) (1012) - Term 43 (EL1014) (1020)' Communication interrupted
```

**Tree structure**

[image: tree structure]

**Online State**

[image: online state]

The EK1100 and EL1014 were changed, but the error stays. Please, can you suggest a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely the problem is that the configured ethercat tree structure does not match the one found.

As you can see the Ethercat master expects *'EK1100-0000-0018'* but finds *'EL1014-XXXX-XXXX'*

Rescan you ethercat tree from the system manager and see if the configured and the found hardware-configuration matches.
Correct your ethercat configuration if you notice errors and reactivate the project.

Specifically take a look at **TERM29**.

There you can probably find the source of your error.
Either a wrong card has been swapped or the ethercat connection is faulty there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Filippo.  I did the scan and added the found configuration.

Now the devices are all in PREOP state, but the following messages occurs:
"Device 2 (Ethercat) needs sync master (at least one variable linked to a task variable).

This means to link an input to the PLC program or something other?

Comment: it means you have no input from your plc task connected to your hardware.Make sure connect at least one input and reactivate again.